# Destroying the caller

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

A `v8::Handle<v8::Object>` packs a native class with some of its members. This is how its meant to work:

```
someobj = window.createNewWrappedClassObject();
[object Object] { fn1:[function], fn2:[function] .... destroy:[function] };

someobj.fn1(); [...] // do something with someobj
someobj.destroy();   // when done, call destroy(). now someobj not only would be
                     // inoperable, it would also get set to {} or null or etc.
```

With `someobj.fn1()`, `someobj.fn2()`, `someobj.destroy()` being the wrapped functions. Initialization logic in constructor looks like this:

```
WrappedClass::GetWrappedObject(){
    Local<ObjectTemplate> objectTemplate = ObjectTemplate::New();
    objectTemplate->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
    this->instance = objectTemplate->NewInstance();
    this->instance->SetPointerInInternalField(0, this);
    this->instance->Set(String::New("fn1"), 
        FunctionTemplate::New(Fn1)->GetFunction());
    [...] // so on
}
```

Now the thing is, when calling `destroy()` what I wanted to do basically was to force all references to that object to become `null`. So here's what I thought:

```
 Handle<Value> WrappedClass::Fn1(const Arguments& args){
    WrappedClass * CurrentInstance = 
        static_cast<WrappedClass *>(args.This()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
    CurrentInstance->~WrappedClass();
    CurrentInstance->instance->Clear(); // tricky part right here and
    args.This()->Clear();               // also here on these two lines
    return v8::Null(); 
}
```

What happens? Nothing happens, the function never actually returns. I fixed this by not calling  `->Clear()` and instead do `someobj = someobj.destroy();` in JS.

But here's the funny part. After running it multiple times, the whole computer was gone crazy. Explorer windows losing fonts, losing  window decorations, system time in taskbar disappearing, start menu showing dark rectangles instead of icons. You name it.

Why did this happen? And how was I supposed to set the calling object to null instead?

Comment: "start menu showing dark rectangles" is a syndrome of GDI resource leak. Windows have limited GDI handles.

Comment: @J-16SDiZ Funny. Is there any way I can see handle counts and stuff like that?

Comment: Try the "Process Explorer" from Microsoft. Google it.